# R code help- Turning column of state names to abbreviations

Tags: r

I'm new to R and need help.

I need to make a function that will transform my column of state names into their appropriate abbreviations. I know that I am going to use state.abb(x, state.names) but am unsure how to do it. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
 df1$col1 <- state.abb[match(df1$col1, state.name)]
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 df1 <- data.frame(col1= sample(state.name, 20, replace=TRUE),
   col2=rnorm(20), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```